# Table users not specified in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I wrote a basic `Login/Registration` system in laravel by using blade system. It is for an experiment. Here is my code:
`register.blade.php`:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And here is my `database/migrations/create_users.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

When I fill in the registration form and submit, I get the following error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 620:   
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'miniNet.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ajaykulkarni178@gmail.com)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: did you run `php artisan migrate` ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that command. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution: never forget to run migrations after creating them:

`php artisan migrate`